# How to display an image in a Meteor Cordova app on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

As it is shown in this screenshot I can access an image from Chrome desktop but not by in Xwalk.
[image]

However, the asset is present in `assets/www/application/app` and in `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.cordova/app`

The actual path of the image is generated by adding `http://localhost:12752/local-filesystem/` before the file path as [stated in the docs](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#accessing-local-files).

Comment: And where is it exactly in the path of your app ? If you unzip the apk, can you find it ?

Comment: Have yo ua software in mind to unzip apk on mac? Note that the image is present in `.meteor/local/build/programs/web.cordova/` but it is like the hot code push system does not take care of the new images.

Comment: Ok find a way by renaming the apk in zip. The asset is also present in the apk. So it is present both in the original apk and the incremental assets bundle served by the server. But the trick is that is not the same path. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should very probably put your static assets like such image in the `[root]/public/` [special folder](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories) of your Meteor project:

> - **public**
>
> All files inside a top-level directory called `public/` are served as-is to the client. When referencing these assets, do not include `public/` in the URL, write the URL as if they were all in the top level. For example, reference `public/bg.png` as `<img src='/bg.png' />`. This is the best place for `favicon.ico`, `robots.txt`, and similar files.

The [page you refer to](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#accessing-local-files) is about accessing files on the device storage (typically once a photo has been taken through a camera plugin), not your app static files:

> […] You can use this to convert URLs received from plugins like `cordova-plugin-file` and `cordova-plugin-camera` for example.